# How to handle multiple elements with the same ID in HTML/AJAX/DJANGO?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django

I have created the functionality to like/dislike posts in my blog but currently it is that the users can only give a like on the `post_detail` page. Now I wanted to improve my page so users do not have to open the `post_detail` view but instead can like posts on the main feed.

With my current code I am facing the issue that multiple html elements share the same ID.. I know that IDs are unique, so I need to somehow create unique IDs but I do not know how I can accomplish that.

Within the `post_detail` page I am having a `div` to include my html template for likes:

```
<div id="like-section">
    {% include 'feed/like_section.html' %}
</div>
```

Within the `like_section` file I have the two buttons for liking/disliking a post:

```
<form action="{% url 'post-likes' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if is_liked %}
        <button type="submit" id="like" name="post_id" value="{{ post.id }}" class="btn btn-secondary btn-danger">Unlike</button>
    {% else %}
        <button type="submit" id="like" name="post_id" value="{{ post.id }}" class="btn btn-secondary">Like</button>
    {% endif %}
</form>
<p class="">{{ post.likes.count }} people liked this post</p>
```

If this form is submitted, the following jQuery code calls my django view:

```
$(document).on('click', '#like', function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                // Primary Key from form is the value of the button!
                var pk = $(this).attr('value');
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '{% url 'post-likes' %}',
                    data: {'post_id': pk, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}' },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(response){
                        $('#like-section').html(response['form']);
                        console.log($('#like-section').html(response['form']));
                    },
                    error: function(rs, e){
                        console.log(rs.responseText);
                    },
                });
            });
```

And finally the django view that adds the user to the liked list:

```
def post_like(request):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=request.POST.get('post_id'))
    if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        post.likes.remove(request.user)
        is_liked = False
    else:
        post.likes.add(request.user)
        is_liked = True

    context =  {
        'post': post,
        'is_liked': is_liked,
    }

    if request.is_ajax():
        html = render_to_string('feed/like_section.html', context, request=request)
        return JsonResponse({'form': html})
```

To keep the button state persistent I am passing the context variable `is_liked` which is a boolean that determines whether the requesting user has liked a post or not.

This works fine if I only have a single post per page but I would like to have multiple posts per page to have a feed where users still are able to like posts.

Comment: why did you use id instead of class

Comment: because when I use class all posts that are displayed get liked when I click on like(at least on the front end, when I reload the page only the post I liked is still liked)

Comment: no your thinking is wrong you all ready use if condition so it will control like and unlike buttons

Comment: I mean the "like" as such gets saved but on the front end when I click the button, all buttons are triggered at once.

Comment: use class and try closet function in jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With respect to what you described (I don't know how you are loading your post), the following is how I do it :

```
views(where you are loading your posts)

def forms(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'posts.html', {'posts': posts})
```

```
posts.html

{% for post in posts %}
    <div post-id="{{ post.pk }}">
       // load other parts
    </div> 
{% endfor %}
```

```
jquery part

$(".your-selector").click(function () {
        var post = $(this).attr('post-id');
        $.ajax({
            url: '/your-url/',
            data: {
                'post': post,
                ....
                },
            type: 'post',
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                  // do stuff on success
                },
        });
    });
```

Now you are loading posts and every `div` has its own id, now you can do it in one page. I think this can solve the problem, do remember this that you need to change your `js` to get `post-id`.

Comment: Yes I am loading my posts like you described with the for loop! But lets say I have post1 with id=1 and post2 with id=2, how can I distinguish between IDs in the event handler of jQuery? Because I am now "hard-coding" the id: `$(document).on('click', '#ID', function(event)`

Comment: @ j.kadel  I added the ```jquery``` part. I'm using the same code in a different scenario and it is working pretty fine. Let me know if that solve your problem. This keyword ```$(this)``` will do the job, distinguishing ids I mean.

Comment: I tried it like this but now my jQuery is not working anymore. I just adjusted the class of the form and the ID of the div container in my jquery. And now the AJAX header is not set.. However the like gets stored in the database so something is wrong with front end

Comment: Okay nevermind my HTML had an error and now it works! Thank you :)